# Move a single Plugin

Tags: plugins

I pretend move a single plugin and respective content from Site A to site B? Exist any plugin backup for that, or other way for it?

The plugin for move is: MyMail

Comment: depends on the plugin

Comment: What to you mean? the plugin as MyMail

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of "containing" the settings of a single plugin in WP. Plugins use core APIs (such as Options) freely to store data.

So on WordPress level to do this the whole plugin's code will need to be examined to have a complete catalog of things which need to be moved.

Plugins themselves might implement their own export/import functionality. If the specific plugin doesn't have it you could suggest it to developer as possible enhancement.